# Tesseract Ocr run on windows phone?

Tags: azure, windows-phone, ocr, tesseract

I have using Tesseract Ocr,Training tesseract ocr engine and combine the data is in order to achieve recognition of numbers display like 7-Segment display.Here is the problem,converting picture to tiff and generate .box file I'm using JTessBoxEditor which need java runtime to support then I run the WPF application to train the Tesseract engine,but it always recognzie 0 as 8.And hwo can I run all this on windows phone?Is that I need create an Virtual  machine on Azure then link it?Or any other way which is easier and faster to done it,let it run on the windows phone?

Answer (score 0):

Solved!I have write an console application to launch command line and execute tesseract and share files to Azure for get result